# How to create group alias mail to send to many users on mail server?

Tags: server, mail-server

I want to create group mail alias like "group@mail.com", sothat when i send email to `group@mail.com`, it sends to `user1@mail.com, user2@mail.com, user3@mail.com`...etc

How to do it using postfix, or any other possible method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably can be done using [mailman](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mailman.html) via lists.

Answer (score 6):

You have two ways of achieving that. You can create postfix aliases, or create a full featured mailing list. This all depends on what you intend to do with such an address.

A group alias would be well suited for automatic notifications to a group of people, while a full mailing list is probably better suited for discussion between a specific group of people.

- For postfix aliases (works on most distros): edit `/etc/aliases` and
  add a line like: `groupname: user1@mail.com, user2@mail.com, ...`. Then, run `postalias /etc/aliases`, and reload the postfix configuration with `postfix reload`.
- For mailing lists: there are various servers out there, the "classic"
  being mailman. Simpa works too. How to install one of those probably would take to long to explain. I would advise you to find a good howto online or to refer to the documentation of one of those tools.